# Average length of a one dimensional array in Java

Tags: java, arrays, average

I am new to the website and programming in general, so bear with me.

My program must meet the following criteria:

1. Reads a positive integer `n`, followed by the (`x,y`) coordinates of `n` points, storing these values in a two-dimensional array named points with `n` rows and two columns.
2. Creates a two-dimensional array with `n` rows and `n` columns named distances, with distances[i][j] = distance from points[i] to points[j].
3. Creates a one dimensional array of length `n` named averages, with averages[i] = average of rows `i` of distances.
4. Determines and prints which of the `n` points has the smallest average distance.

The part I seem to be stumped on part #3, how would I compute the average distance of rows?

Here is my code thus far, if anyone can help me complete it I would greatly appreciate. Also point out any mistakes in what I do have.

```
import java.util.Scanner;

  public class Java
  {    
      public static void main( String[] args )
      {    
          Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in );    
          System.out.print("How many points: ");    
          int n = input.nextInt();    
          double[][] points = new double[n][2];    
          for(int i = 0; i < n; i++)
          {    
              //prompt or and get coordinates    
              //points[i][0] = input.nextDouble();    
              //points[i][1] = input.nextDouble();    
          }    
          double[][] distances = new double[n][n];    
          for(int i = 0; i < n; i++)    
              for(int j = 0; j < n; j++)    
                  distances[i][j] = distance(points[i], points[j]);    
          double[] averages = new double[n];    
          for(int i = 0; i < n; i++)    
              averages[i] = average( distances[i] );    
          int which_one = minimum_location( averages );    
          System.out.printf("Point # %d has a smallest average of %f\n", which_one,    
                  averages[which_one]);    
      }    
      public static double distance    
      (double x1, double y1, double x2, double y2)    
      {    
          return Math.sqrt((x2 - x1) * (x2 - x1) + (y2 - y1) * (y2 - y1));    
      }

      {    
          public static double average( double[] x);    
          //problem area    
      }

      {    
          public static int minimum_location( double[] x );    
          if (shortestDistance > distance);    
          {    
              p1 = i;    
              p2 = j;    
              shortestDistance = distance;    
          }    
      }
```

Comment: #3 is asking for avg[i] to be the average of distance[i][0]..distance[i][n].  It's the same as asking for the average of a 1d array, because the first term is constant for each average you're computing.

Answer (score 0):

This should do it:

```
public static double average(double[] x)
{
   double avg = 0;
   for (double d: x)
     avg += d;
   avg /= x.length;
   return avg;
}
```